# When using DTLS with UDP sockets on OpenSSL, how do you properly handle the connection and SSL session?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, network-programming, udp

With TCP it is pretty easy because is connection-based and once a connection is established you can set up the SSL object associated with that connection once and stream data...UDP however is connection-less, so does this mean I have to set up a new SSL object for each UDP packet I get from a client? Is there a way I could use the same SSL object for subsequent reads from the socket as long as I'm talking to the same client?

Comment: See [OpenSSL DTLS API](https://gist.github.com/Jxck/b211a12423622fe304d2370b1f1d30d5) and [Net-SNMP DTLS Implementation Notes](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/DTLS_Implementation_Notes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with UDP you can still "bind" and "connect" a socket. If you are using OpenSSL then use DTLSv1_listen() to await a connection from a new client. When one arrives, create a new socket which is connected to the client's address/port and use a new SSL object for that socket. All subsequent DTLS packets to/from that client can use the same SSL object.