# Connecting to DTLS in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, datagram

Is there any way to connect to DTLS socket in PHP? Some undocumented feature maybe, or not so popular extension? For what I've tried, there's no possibility, but I'm always hoping that I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you find a way to connect to DTLS in PHP ?

Comment: @neoteknic Unfortunately not.

Comment: Maybe not possible nativly, post a php feature request ?

Comment: Still no update about this ?

Comment: Did you try this package? https://github.com/amphp/socket

Comment: OpenSSL has support for DTLS 1.0 and DTLS 1.2. Have you tried OpenSSL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529927/when-using-dtls-with-udp-sockets-on-openssl-how-do-you-properly-handle-the-conn

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370966/connecting-to-websocket-with-php-client

Comment: @ArunP we're looking for DTLS support in PHP, not for websockets. Completely different things.

Comment: @odan Not tried it, do you have a simple PHP example to init a DTLS connect in php ?

Comment: this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php could help. Did you try stream_socket_client? It could work if openSSL implements DTLS support.

Comment: @Lety stream_socket_client with ? udp:// (no tls?) tls:// (but tls is tcp ... ?)

Comment: @neoteknic reading php manual "The ssl:// and tls:// transports (available only when openssl support is compiled into PHP) are extensions of the tcp:// transport which include SSL encryption. Since PHP 4.3.0 OpenSSL support must be statically compiled into PHP, since PHP 5.0.0 it may be compiled as a module or statically. " So I guess that if openSSL support dtls, it could be that dtls://host:port works, but I can't try it. DTLS is TLS over datagram transport, here is the specification https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6347 while TLS normally is over TCP, the specification is rfc5246

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a turn key library or extension out there to do what you are asking but that doesn't mean it is not possible.

PHP Does have UDP socket support via [socket_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) + SOCK_DGRAM and TLS support via [OpenSSL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).  In theory, you should be able to use both these to provide a secure data-gram to any system, but it's hard to say for sure as your question is pretty generic.  Please keep in mind that non-privileged users cannot open data-gram sockets on most *NIX systems.  This restriction also applies to ports < 1024.

Comment: I think you meant non-privileged users cannot open raw sockets, udp and tcp should have identical port restrictions.

Comment: I know it but I never  succeed to do it, I want a connection to a Phillips hue bridge entrainement API (different than REST http api), just need an example. No problem if it's root only.

Comment: The php wrapper only includes a few capabilities, and nothing like what is needed to use dtls, for example DTLS_client_method appears needed: https://github.com/nplab/DTLS-Examples/search?q=DTLS_client_method&unscoped_q=DTLS_client_method
but isn't referenced in the php docs or source: https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=DTLS_client_method&unscoped_q=DTLS_client_method

Answer (score 0):

It can now works with php + swoole extension !
This kind of code should work :

```
$client = new Swoole\Coroutine\Client(SWOOLE_SOCK_UDP | SWOOLE_SSL);
if (!$client->connect('192.168.0.10', 2100)) {
    exit("connect failed\n");
}
$client->send("ping");
```

Need to test it & fix to improve my answer

Doc :
https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-dtls (thank @mlask)

Comment: It looks like you’re right - https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-dtls